# How to clear NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If I perform a fetch w/ a NSFetchedResultsController that returns objects and then want to clear the controller, i.e., have .fetchedObjects be an empty array, is there a method that can be called or do I have to perform another fetch that does not return any results?

Comment: Set NSFetchedResultsController to nil.

Comment: This would not work with the lazy instantiation typical for FRC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could set the fetch request of your fetched results controller to return nothing:

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = 
   [NSPredicate  predicateWithValue:NO];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil]
```

Now `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` should return an empty array.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. It just seems strange there is no method to clear the results and that you have to perform an unnecessary fetch to clear the controller.

Comment: Well, it's really just two lines of code, and it does not accomplish anything really useful. You could always write these code into a method name of your liking as a category on the FRC.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't have a `predicate` property. I believe you meant `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate`.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make a lot of sense. An `NSFetchedResultsController`'s data is the result of a fetch request. For `fetchedObjects` to be empty, the fetch request would have to return an empty set. That would imply that there were no objects satisfying the fetch request. If there *are* objects that satisfy the request, then `fetchedObjects` will not be empty. What you're asking amounts to asking how to ensure that a fetch has no results.

I'm not even sure why you'd want this. If you're not going to be using the results of the fetch any more, just get rid of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Why keep it around if you don't want its results any more?

Comment: You would want it in the case where you have a view controller using the results of an NSFetchedResultsController as a datasource and you need that datasource to be cleared.